# How to completely uninstall docker

Tags: 16.04, docker

I followed the uninstall instructions [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#prerequisites). Then I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-get purge docker-engine
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge docker-engine
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

So after I did all this I ran this command to see if docker files are any where else:

```
sudo find / -name '*docker*'
```

I found several places where docker files still exists.

```
/etc
/sys
/lib
/usr
/usr
/run
/proc
/var
```

Docker exists in subfolders in the list above. I can post every path if you like. There is about 200 locations.

Is there a way to totally and completely remove docker everywhere?

Answer (score 481, accepted):

To completely uninstall Docker:

*Step 1*

```bash
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
```

To identify what installed package you have:

*Step 2*

```bash
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-compose-plugin
```

The above commands will not remove images, containers, volumes, or user created configuration files on your host. If you wish to delete all images, containers, and volumes run the following commands:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
```

You have removed Docker from the system completely.

Comment: Additionally I had to delete `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`.

Comment: I also remembered to remove the `/etc/docker` directory and all contents

Comment: I see Docker related entries when `$ sudo iptables -L` after this.

Comment: @eugene I also able to see Docker related entries, Any suggestion what i need to do now.

Comment: @Devansh I ran https://serverfault.com/a/200658/184963 but it clears everything.. so be warned.. I didn't have any rules setup except what docker added.

Comment: In my case, I had to use `sudo apt-get purge docker-ce-cli` as well.

Comment: i also had to remove `~/.docker` directory

Comment: If all this fails then you may have installed it with snap. lol.

Comment: There is probably another way that doesn't involve rebooting, but rebooting will remove the left-over entries from `sudo iptables -L`.

Comment: Don't work for me with docker 19.03

Comment: @WeAreAllMonica , I tried to [delete all docker rules one by one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50084968/1626977) and then I [removed the chains](https://serverfault.com/a/564062/253290) as well.

Comment: I removed chains and rules [with](https://serverfault.com/questions/375981/delete-a-iptables-chain-with-its-all-rules#comment384145_375981) `iptables-save | grep -v -i docker | iptables-restore`, with a [backup first](https://serverfault.com/a/183535/407820): `iptables-save > $(date -I)-iptables.save`

Comment: Also `sudo rm /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg`

Comment: it makes sens to remove all data (images, volumes, network..) by docker first by using the command "docker system prune -a", and then remove docker package itself

Comment: I also had to include `containerd.io` in the commands

Comment: Also run `ip link delete docker0` to get rid of annoying message `IPv4 address for docker0:         172.17.0.1` when you login.

Comment: In my system the package was named `containerd.io` too

Comment: The incantation that worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 was `sudo apt-get remove docker docker.io containerd runc`.

Comment: I still see docker-buildx-plugin after running all those commands  and then again `dpkg -l | grep -i docker` . Revoved it by running `sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin docker-ce-rootless-extras
`

So I think first thing to run is the things from docs.

Answer (score 47):

If you are on Ubuntu, I find it much easier to uninstall docker if it is installed with `snap`. You simply do:

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

or, to avoid it creating back-up data for a snap you no longer require:

```
sudo snap remove --purge docker
```

To find any potentially remaining files, you can run

```
sudo find / -name "*docker*"
```

If you want to delete everything listed (**be careful because this is typically not what you actually want**), you can run,

```
sudo find / -name "*docker*" -exec `rm -rf` {} +
```

#### IMPORTANT UPDATES

As mentioned in the comments,

> The second part is not needed and just dangerous, at least run it without `` -exec `rm -rf` {} + `` first

and

> The second part could delete files that belong to different packages, e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/dockerfile.vim`

So better to see what is going to be deleted first.

Comment: the `snap` command is well enough but take care before you delete everything on your system with `docker` in the name!

Comment: You saved my MAAS box :)

Comment: sudo find / -name "*docker*" -exec `rm -rf` {} + 2>/dev/null is what works for me

Comment: The second part is not needed and just dangerous, at least run it without `-exec \`rm -rf\` {} +` first.

Comment: The second part could delete files that belong to different packages, e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/dockerfile.vim`

Comment: That last `find` command has the potential to do more harm than good.

Answer (score 31):

Collaborated list collected from above posts and comments fro removing docker and docker-compose:

```
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce  
sudo umount /var/lib/docker/
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 15):

Add docker-ce-cli package also while doing purge of docker

```sh
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli
```

Answer (score 8):

## An update on uninstalling docker

*Just an update on this, after I had to deal with the same issue.*

Here is the [official docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#uninstall-docker-engine) on removing docker.

### Remove the latest version:

*Uninstall the Docker Engine, CLI, and Containerd packages:*

```sh
sudo apt-get purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

*Delete all images, containers, and volumes:*

```sh
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
```

### Remove previous versions:

```sh
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

Answer (score 7):

Steps performed in order to remove docker on Centos 7:

```
yum list installed|grep -i docker
yum remove containerd.io.x86_64 docker-ce.x86_64 docker-ce-cli.x86_64
groupdel docker
ls /var/lib/docker/
rm -rf  /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
rm -rf  /var/run/docker.sock 
rm -rf  /var/run/docker
find /var -iname "*docker*"
```

Hope this information could be helpful for someone.

Best regards,

Answer (score 3):

Remove docker completly

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
sudo apt remove --purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt autoclean
```

Answer (score 2):

**Refreshing installation of Docker desktop and docker-ce after testing installation of Docker Desktop**

After uninstalling docker desktop from ubuntu 22.04 and docker-ce (removing everything)

Then reinstalling docker engine (ce) alone as I want to run docker instance on host and separately on qemu/virt and being able to run hello-world I was getting this error

$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///home/christian/.docker/desktop/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Despite the user having docker group membership and permissions.

What was happening that despite uninstalling docker-desktop completely and docker-ce and then reinstalling from scratch I kept getting this error.
There was no .docker/desktop/ folder

I found a config.json file
.docker/config.json

that had a line
"credsStore": "desktop",
"currentContext": "desktop-linux"

So I copied it to a .bak extension and from then docker commands  work properly without sudo

So it looks like uninstalling Docker Desktop is leaving at least that leftover behind.

Answer (score 2):

```
// check docker is installed or not
dpkg -l | grep -i docker

// remove volume , network , container and image files
sudo docker volume prune -f
sudo docker network prune -f
sudo docker container prune -f
sudo docker image prune -a

// remove docker
sudo apt purge docker
or
sudo apt remove docker

// remove dependency packages related to docker
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt autoclean
```

for details : [read](https://alpondith.medium.com/completely-uninstall-docker-in-linux-f8cad7297eaf)

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the packages those files originated from with a command like `dpkg-query -S $(sudo find / -name '*docker*' -print 2>/dev/null)`. Any such packages that you do not need, you can remove with `sudo apt-get purge <package>`. Please use care when you do so as some packages include some support for docker, but you might not want to remove, say, a text editor or a file manager for that reason.

If some files did not originate from packages (indicated by "dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *path*"), you can remove them individually. Again, please use caution, as there may be files unrelated to the docker you want to remove, which simply have the string "docker" in their names.

Comment: The dpkg query gives thousands of `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern` which is not very useful.