# In Ubuntu 20.04 can't use nvidia docker

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, docker

I recently updated from ubuntu 18.04 to ubuntu 20.04. 
I would like to develop on ubuntu 20.04 with nvidia-docker.

When I try to use the docker with the updated version, I get the following error.

```
docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

Then I uninstalled the docker system according to [this cite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker#:~:text=5%20Answers&text=You%20have%20removed%20Docker%20from%20the%20system%20completely.&text=You%20can%20identify%20the%20packages,%2Dget%20purge%20.) and reinstalled it according to [this site](https://illya13.github.io/RL/tutorial/2020/04/27/installing-tensorflow-in-docker-on-ubuntu-20.html).

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this instructions for install docker-nvidia and docker-compose :

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt-get update
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
sudo apt-get install docker-ce=18.03.1~ce~3-0~ubuntu
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/gpgkey | \
  sudo apt-key add -
distribution=$(. /etc/os-release;echo $ID$VERSION_ID)
curl -s -L https://nvidia.github.io/nvidia-docker/$distribution/nvidia-docker.list | \
  sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nvidia-docker.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-docker2
sudo pkill -SIGHUP dockerd
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo groupadd docker
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: Right now I've got `nvidia-docker2` working without `docker-ce` - it actually works with `docker.io` >= 18.x. So if you have the off-the-shelf docker, you're fine.

Comment: I followed this instruction and every step worked. However, it changed nothing. I still get the same `Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]]`

Answer (score 0):

unistall docker now in my pc(follow [this cite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker#:%7E:text=5%20Answers&text=You%20have%20removed%20Docker%20from%20the%20system%20completely.&text=You%20can%20identify%20the%20packages,%2Dget%20purge%20.)).

And follow this [cite](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/).