# L2TP VPN connected but no traffic / not working

Tags: vpn, iptables, docker, resolv.conf, l2tp

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 and having issues with L2TP VPN

By the way it was working fine up until today, would connect and all traffic was fine. Now the VPN connects but I cant do anything.. even [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) doesnt work.

The strange thing is that I have another machine with the same OS and I set up the VPN there and it works fine. Also, I had the same issue before (twice!).. reinstalled kubuntu and it worked fine again! I don't want to re-install kubuntu again as it's a pain in the backside to set up everything I need.

By the way, following this solution seems to partly solve it: [How to disable systemd-resolved in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/907246/how-to-disable-systemd-resolved-in-ubuntu?newreg=6ff07e1b5ee0467da8fca490440ef148)

The problem with the above solution is that the VPN becomes extremely slow. Anyone know what the problem is and how I can solve it? Like I say if I install the OS freshly then it works perfectly fine.. but then after a few weeks I get the issue again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had lots of rules in `iptables` related to docker (I use docker a lot), so decided to uninstall docker completely. After the purge I rebooted and then connected the VPN and it worked fine.

So, it worked without any changes to systemd-resolved - i.e. the OS was configured as it would be out of the box

Somewhere along the line of using docker it starts to interfere with my VPN by the changes it makes to the iptables!

Uninstalling docker solved my problem... I am going to reinstall docker and will probably hit the same issue again eventually!

[How to completely uninstall docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker)

###Edit
I think this is the best solution and has worked for me
https://www.lullabot.com/articles/fixing-docker-and-vpn-ip-address-conflicts

In case the article gets taken down the solution in a nutshell is create a `daemon.json` as follows

```
    $ vi /etc/docker/daemon.json
    {
      "default-address-pools" : [
        {
          "base" : "172.240.0.0/16",
          "size" : 24
        }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to uninstall docker totally. If you disable the bridge that docker made in your system, your problem might solved!

Check out the following links:

- [How to delete interface docker0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40082608/how-to-delete-interface-docker0)
- [How to delete/disable docker0 bridge on docker startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52146056/how-to-delete-disable-docker0-bridge-on-docker-startup)

Comment: Thanks @MoYa, I will try that the next time I have the problem. I will report back here to let you know if it works

Comment: @JohnHarrison. It could help. Thanks

Comment: I also found this which looks like a nice way of fixing it https://www.lullabot.com/articles/fixing-docker-and-vpn-ip-address-conflicts