# Docker-ce refuses to install (18.04)

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, docker

I have attempted to install `docker-ce` for hours now without success.
I am running vanilla 18.04 and have used both the [official](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) and the [DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) installation guides which both produce the same error.

Attempted solutions:

- [this step-by-step answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker) to remove Docker completely before any reattempt.
- I have downloaded and tried older versions per the advise from [this blog post](https://medium.com/@randima.somathilaka/docker-engine-install-fails-in-ubuntu-3e70762c2187)
- I have disabled my VPN service which has been suggested elsewhere on AskUbuntu.

Output `sudo apt-get install docker-ce`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.13~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-13 16:33:18 CET; 7ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 14405 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14405 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Output `systemctl status docker.service`:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-11-13 16:33:25 CET; 4min 36s ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 14540 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 14540 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 13 16:33:25 biskop systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Any help would be **greatly** appreciated.