# Uninstall docker completely

Tags: docker

I ran all the statements referenced [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker) to remove docker. Yet, from the terminal,

```
docker run hello-world
```

still runs and creates a container.

Meanwhile

```
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i docker
```

shows no docker packages installed.

I am running Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon.

Comment: Unfortunately, after I answered, I realize you are using Linux Mint, which is off-topic for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you still have the snap version of docker installed. Run this:

```
snap list
```

And see if docker is listed. If it is, then run

```
sudo snap remove docker
```

Now docker should be completely removed, both as snap and deb package.