# Ubuntu 20.04 takes more time to boot and shutdown after installing docker

Tags: boot, 20.04, docker, acer

I installed docker on my ubuntu 20.04. After that my machine boot time and shutdown time increased. So I uninstalled docker.io from my machine but still my machine takes more time to boot and shutdown. I don't know what to do.

Edit: Docker is completely uninstalled, there is no docker service running. Used this thread as reference [How to completely uninstall docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker) to uninstall docker.

Commands used to uninstall docker

```
$ sudo apt remove docker.io
$ dpkg -l | grep -i docker
$ sudo apt remove --purge docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd
$ sudo apt autoremove -y
$ sudo apt autoclean
$ sudo apt purge docker.io
```

Comment: I suggest you read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/935569/1438484). If you only uninstalled that one package, that is why Docker isn't fully gone

Comment: I read the thread and did it what they said.

Comment: And...? Did it work? If not, please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo service docker status`

Comment: thanks added few more details

Comment: As the machine boots and shuts down hit the escape key to see what is happehing.  There most likely will be a message like " stop job for . . . waiting "

Comment: Useful to me but the still I'm unable to find which one making slow boot my machine. What are the information I need to share here.