# Can't get rid of docker-compose even after following tutorial

Tags: 22.04, docker

```bash
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

I am trying to delete and uninstall everything docker related so that I can make a clean re-install.
I have followed these tutorials:
[How to completely uninstall docker](https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker)
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/uninstall/

I have run the following commands in order:

```bash
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker /etc/docker
sudo rm /etc/apparmor.d/docker
sudo groupdel docker
sudo rm -rf /var/run/docker.sock
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-compose-plugin
sudo apt-get autoremove -y --purge docker-engine docker docker.io docker-ce docker-compose-plugin
```

And I thought I got rid of it, but then:

```bash
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
ii  docker-compose                             1.29.2-1                                all          define and run multi-container Docker applications with YAML
ii  python3-docker                             5.0.3-1                                 all          Python 3 wrapper to access docker.io's control socket
ii  python3-dockerpty                          0.4.1-2                                 all          Pseudo-tty handler for docker Python client (Python 3.x)
```

I still have `docker-compose                             1.29.2-1`   and this one won't go away no matter the command:

```bash
sudo apt-get purge -y docker-componse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-componse

sudo apt-get remove docker-compose-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker-compose-plugin' is not installed, so not removed

rm $DOCKER_CONFIG/cli-plugins/docker-compose
rm: cannot remove '/cli-plugins/docker-compose': No such file or directory

rm /usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/lib/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose': No such file or directory

sudo snap remove docker
snap "docker" is not installed

rm /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose': No such file or directory

sudo apt-get purge docker-ce-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker-ce-cli' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 34 not upgraded.

rm -r /home/george/.docker

sudo rm $(which docker-compose)

dpkg -l | grep -i docker
ii  docker-compose                             1.29.2-1                                all          define and run multi-container Docker applications with YAML
ii  python3-docker                             5.0.3-1                                 all          Python 3 wrapper to access docker.io's control socket
ii  python3-dockerpty                          0.4.1-2                                 all          Pseudo-tty handler for docker Python client (Python 3.x)
```

`which docker-compose` return nothing.

`docker-compose                             1.29.2-1` is still there.

What is that and how can I get rid of it ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the old version of Docker compose, which is not in the current repos.

Try uninstalling directly with `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -P docker-compose
```

This does not check for any repos or dependencies, and simply purge the package, no questions asked.